# Is __dirname the code folder or the parent project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

So, I was wondering if I write a node module and reference __dirname in it, Will it return the node module's directory or the parent project that's using the module's directory.

Comment: It returns the directory of the file using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__dirname` is an environment variable that tells you the absolute path of the directory containing the currently executing file.

Only the directory, not the file itself.

Comment: It's not an environment variable.  It's a module-scoped variable.  Each CommonJS module has its own version of `__dirname`.